# Solve $2xy+y^2-2x^2\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=0$; $y=2$ when $x=1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, logarithms, absolute-value

> $2xy+y^2-2x^2\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=0$; $y=2$ when $x=1$.

My reference gives the solution $y=\dfrac{2x}{1-\log x}$, but is it really the solution ?

**My Attempt**
$$
2xy+y^2-2x^2\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=0\implies\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\dfrac{2xy+y^2}{2x^2}=\frac{y}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{y^2}{x^2}\\
\text{Put }v=\frac{y}{x}\implies y=vx\\
\dfrac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=v+x\dfrac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}=v+\frac12v^2\implies x\dfrac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{2}v^2\\
2\int v^{-2}dv=\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}\implies -\frac{2}{v}=\log|x|+C\\
\boxed{\frac{-2x}{y}=\log|x|+C}
$$
$y=2$ when $x=1$$\implies C=-1$,
$$
\frac{-2x}{y}=\log|x|-1\implies \color{red}{y=\dfrac{2x}{1-\log|x|}}
$$
How do I justify going from $y=\dfrac{2x}{1-\log\color{red}{|}x\color{red}{|}}$ to $y=\dfrac{2x}{1-\log x}$ ?

**What I understand**

I only have basic knowledge on differential equations, thus not familiar with the ideas like singularity and all.

I think I only understand a hint,
$$
y=\dfrac{2x}{1-\log|x|}\implies y=\begin{cases}\dfrac{2x}{1-\log x} \text{ for } x>0\\\dfrac{2x}{1-\log(-x)} \text{ for } x<0\end{cases}
$$
So the condition "$y=2$ when $x=1$" does not include in the second case. Does this has something to do with my doubt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, the differential equation is not defined for $x=0$. The equation in its original form exists, but at $x=0$ it does not contain any derivatives. Thus the domain in the $(x,y)$ space consists of two disjoint components, one with $x>0$ and one with $x<0$. Solutions of the ODE can have their graph in only one of the components

The initial condition tells us that the maximal interval for the solution has to be inside $(0,\infty)$. On that interval, $\log|x|=\log x$.

The solution formula tells us that any solution in both components can be continuously extended to the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$, so that any pair of solutions, one from each component, can be joined to form a function that could be said to be a solution in some extended sense.

Comment: thanx. i think thats whr my doubt really is, how does the initial condition tells us the maximal interval for the solution is $(0,\infty)$ ?

Comment: The plane $x=0$ in $(x,y,y')$ phase/state space is a singularity for the differential equation, it divides the domain of the ODE in explicit form $y''=f(x,y,y')$ into two halves. The initial point is in the half-space $x>0$, thus any solution through this initial point will have to stay in the same half-space.

Comment: ok well. actually i am not familiar with singularity and all. could u bit simplify ur explanation if i have only basic knowledge abt differential equations.

Comment: That is just a more general way to say that you would have to divide by zero, or that you get a vertical slope, which is not defined and thus these points can not be inside the domain of a differential equation.

Comment: I think I only understand, $y=\dfrac{2x}{1-\log|x|}\implies y=\begin{cases}\dfrac{2x}{1-\log x} \text{ for } x>0\\\dfrac{2x}{1-\log(-x)} \text{ for } x<0\end{cases}$. So the condition "$y=2$ when $x=1$" does not include in the second case. Does this has something to do with my doubt ?

Comment: There is no specific $C$ for $x<0$. You can continue the part for $x>0$ with any constant in the solution formula. This is sometimes possible, that one can continue a solution over a definition gap in the ODE. But still, the ODE, the function $f$, is not defined for $x=0$ and any solution of the ODE exists only inside the domain of $f$. And that domain has two disjoint parts, $x<0$ and $x>0$ and no solution in the proper sense can cross from one part to the other.

Comment: $$
y=\dfrac{-2x}{\log|x|+C}\implies y=\begin{cases}\dfrac{-2x}{\log x+C} \text{ for } x>0\\\dfrac{-2x}{\log(-x)+C} \text{ for } x<0\end{cases}
$$
are the general solution of the differential equation. The condition "$y=2$ when $x=1$" is only applicable for the case one due to domain restrictions, thus $C=-1$ is only for the first case. Thus, the particular solution for "$y=2$ when $x=1$" is $y=\dfrac{2x}{1-\log x}$. Right ?

Comment: The constants $C$ can be different, as they belong to different solutions. Any solution of this form has limit $y\to0$ for $x\to0$ and thus you can combine branches with any combinations of constants to a solution that is continuous at $x=0$.